# How to limit LEFT JOIN to one result AND return lowest value from the result set?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.likes
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```

How could that left join be modified to make it do the following:

```
SELECT likes FROM table_2 WHERE name = [name from table 1] ORDER BY likes ASC
```

I tried writing a subquery, but it didn't work because (I assume) you can't use a variable from outside the subquery (e.g. the name) inside the subquery (the name is not constant, as the result set from the query will be more than one).

Is that possible to do?

EDIT: The tables would be something like this:

table_1:

```
+------+--------+
| id   |  name  |
+------+--------+
|  0   |  cat   |
|  1   |  dog   |
+------+--------+
```

table 2:

```
+------+--------+---------+
| id   |  name  |  likes  |
+------+--------+---------+
|  0   |  cat   |   23    |
|  1   |  cat   |   2     |
|  2   |  cat   |   53    |
|  3   |  dog   |   25    |
|  4   |  dog   |   12    |
+------+--------+---------+
```

So, what I'm wanting is:

```
+--------+---------+
|  name  |  likes  |
+--------+---------+
|  cat   |   2     |
|  dog   |   12    |
+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Do you want the minimum value of the `likes` column for each `name`? Please clarify: what question about your data are you trying to answer?

Comment: @ZaneBien - I updated my question with example tables. Yes, I want the minimum likes for each name.

Comment: Okay, my first solution should be the simplest for what you're trying to achieve. You do not need a join if all you need is the `name` and minimum of `likes`.

Comment: @ZaneBien - there are other left joins in my real query, though, and there is more data being pulled from table_1. Sorry for not mentioning that!

Comment: Then you'll have to refer to the second codebox in my answer where you wrap the result of the minimum selection in a subselect. You can then easily `LEFT JOIN` on the result of that subselect using the `name` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.name, t2.likes
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    name,
    MIN(likes) as likes 
    FROM table_2 
    GROUP BY name
) as t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```

You can do it with a subquery too but i think that will be slower:

```
SELECT 
    t1.name,
    (SELECT MIN(likes) FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.name = t1.name)
FROM table_1 t1
```

Answer (score 2):

Minimum `likes` per name:

```
SELECT   name, MIN(likes) AS likes
FROM     table_2
GROUP BY name
```

If you need more information about the `name`, do a join to the `table_1` table, incorporating the above query into a subselect:

```
SELECT a.name, b.likes
FROM   table_1 a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT   name, MIN(likes) AS likes
    FROM     table_2
    GROUP BY name
) b ON a.name = b.name
```